# Roots of $z^{11}-2z^6+z^4+10i$ in upper half plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have this problem:

> How many times the polynomial $P(z)=z^{11}-2z^6+z^4+10i$ goes to zero in the upper half plane?

Obviously I need the zeros of $P(z)$, and I thought it would be useful the Rouché theorem.

For that I thought it was a good idea to get a disc to bound the problem, and it was considering $\vert z\vert =2$ and $g(z)=z^{11}$. Now, with it I obtained that the zeros were inside that disc. My problem is how to count the number of zeros in $B_2(0)\cap R$ with $R=\{z\colon \Im(z)\geq 0\}$. Can anyone help me how to do that?

Comment: Why not just use newton's method to find all the roots?

Comment: First observe that there are no real roots because of that $10i$. So, we can just compute the winding number of the the image of the real line by the polynomial with respect to the origin. Then, we use the argument principle. Observe that the imaginary part of the image of the real line is always $10i$.

Comment: [This is the best approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1570697/466533) for this kind of problems. Sorry, this problem appears so often that I fill lazy today to reproduce the computation for this case. (Plus I am cooking). Don't get scared by the length of the linked answer, most of the text is for the reader to understand an not really the actual computational work required.

Comment: Another advice. Rouche' is not your friend. For most of these root-counting problems it is not really a feasible approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, since there are still no answers let me try.

One the real line there are no roots and the image of the real line by $P(z)$ lies inside the line $\Im(z)=10$.

The standard work, consider a large semi-circle with diameter lying on the real line (center at the origin for convenience) an containing all the roots of $P$ in the upper half plane. Call the radius $R$. The image of the diameter we know where it is, an the image of the circular part is close to the image of $R^{11}e^{11\theta i}$ where $\theta$ travels $[0,\pi]$. So, for $\theta=0$ the image lies near the point $R^{11}+10i$, for $\theta=\pi$ the image lies near the point $R^{11}e^{11\pi i}+10i=R^{11}e^{\pi i}+10i$. There are $\theta=2pi/11, 4\pi/11, 6\pi/11, 8\pi/11$, and $10\pi/11$, a total of $5$ winds around the origin.

So, $5$ roots in the upper half-plane.

No thinking, only computation. No Rouche'.